# Building rtmpdump on RHEL x86 without yum and no root rights

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, yum

I have an `ssh` connection to a RHEL x86 machine, and I can't use `yum` and I don't have root rights.

Is there a way to still install `rtmpdump`? By looking at [this](http://www.khattam.info/install-rtmpdump-in-centos-5-2010-09-28.html) tutorial, it seems that installing `rtmpdump` on CentOS (as I understand, CentOS and RHEL are similar) is pretty easy, but only if you have `yum`?

So what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

#### Method #1 - compile it yourself directly on box

Sure you should be able to download `rtmpdump` in source form and compile it either on that box, assuming this box has the necessary tools such as `gcc` to compile it.

#### Method #2 - compile it on another box, copy to box

If that isn't an option you could compile it on another box that is comparable, ie. another CentOS box, and then use `scp` to copy the resulting binaries into your home directory, perhaps into `$HOME/rtmpdumpdir`, and run them from there.

#### Method #3 - Extract contents using cpio or rpm2cpio

You could also use the command line tool `cpio` to take the RPM file that contains  the binary distribution of `rtmpdump` and unpack it into a different directory, again something like `$HOME/rtmpdumpdir`. Specifically there's a tool called `rpm2cpio` that can unpack an RPM.

```
$ rpm2cpio myrpmfile.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

#### Other methods

There are other methods discussed in this ServerFault Q&A titled: [rpm without root](https://serverfault.com/questions/100189/rpm-without-root), but I wouldn't expect much from these methods. Installing RPM packages using `rpm` without root can be tricky.

#### References

- [HowTo: Extract an RPM Package Files Without Installing It](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html)